# Can I see database contents in flutter? Where to find the sqlite file from the emulator?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

1 /data/user/0/com.quadauq.foodbuoy/app_flutter/sqlite.db. This is the path of my sqlite file inside emulator, how to copy this file and see the contents?

Comment: type `adb shell` in the terminal and then `sqlite3 /data/user/0/com.quadauq.foodbuoy/app_flutter/sqlite.db`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, inaccessible or notfound issue coming

Comment: `"inaccessible or notfound issue coming"` what do you mean?

Comment: C:\Users\QUADPRO 3\AndroidStudioProjects\FoodBuoyOriginalBackup\foodbuoy>adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ sqlite3 /data/user/0/com.quadauq.foodbuoy/app_flutter/foodbuoy.db
/system/bin/sh: sqlite3: inaccessible or not found

Comment: what emulator is it? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3 should be installed on most emulators

Comment: I am using android emulator only, created from avd manager, but the project is in flutter

Comment: 127|generic_x86:/ $ ls /system/xbin/sqlite*
ls: /system/xbin/sqlite*: No such file or directory